# Apply master theorem on T(n) = T(n/2) + n

Tags: algorithm, recursion, master-theorem

I was just trying my hand on Master Theorem and got a little confused when I was trying to evaluate T(n) = T(n/2) + n. Using Master theorem, the answer evaluates to O(n).

But just go through the below code:

```
fun(n)
{
    if(n == 1)
        return ;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    fun(n/2);
}
```

The recursion equation for the above code is T(n) = T(n/2) + n. Thus the time complexity for  the above program must be O(n).

But if you think logically, the number of times the program runs is:
n+n/2+n/4+n/8+...... = nlogn.
So, logically the time complexity for the above program must be O(nlogn).

I am very much confused now. Can someone please help me out where I am getting it wrong?

Answer (score 5):

No, the serie evaluates to 2n.

> n+n/2+n/4+n/8+...... = 2n

But if you had T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n, then it would be O( n log n )

Comment: oh.. yes.. got it.. i got mixed up with another series.. that evaluates to logn. Thanks a lot !!